# What is the Order (Big O) of this polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, notation, computational-complexity

$$\frac{2n^{14} + 7 n^8 - 3}{3n^8 - n^4 + 3}$$

If this division is $p(n)$, I have to write $p(n) = O(n^k)$

I guess the answer is $n^6$, but how can i solve it step by step?

Comment: @openspace : please, don't if you don't know !

Comment: @Surp I just try to rewrite it.. Sorry, I think that Natalie means another expression.

Comment: Two pieces of relevant nitpickery: (1) I presume you mean as $n\to\infty$, since $n$ is usually used for integer variables, but note that $p(n)$ is $\in O(1)$ as $n\to 0$, for instance - knowing what your asymptote is matters! (2) You (or your instructor) probably pedantically mean $\Theta()$ - it's also completely true to say that $p(n)\in O(n^{14})$ as $n\to\infty$, because $O()$ only talks about _upper bounds_, not precise orders. (Also, (3) strictly speaking $p(n)$ isn't a polynomial, but that's another matter entirely.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step by step :

- $\frac {2n^{14} + 7 n^8 -3} {3n^8 - n^4 + 3}=\frac {n^{14}} {n^8}\frac {2 + 7 n^{-6} -3n^{-14}} {3 - n^{-4} + 3n^{-8}}$
- When $n\longrightarrow \infty$, the right side fraction has finite limit $\frac 2 3$, so it is bounded. Let $B\in\mathbb R$ be this bound.
- $\frac {2n^{14} + 7 n^8 -3} {3n^8 - n^4 + 3}=n^{6}\frac {2 + 7 n^{-6} -3n^{-14}} {3 - n^{-4} + 3n^{-8}}\leqslant n^6B$

Hence $O(n^6)$

Answer (score 1):

Since $$\frac{2n^{14}+7n^8-3}{3n^8-n^4+3}=\frac{2n^6+7-\frac{3}{n^8}}{3-\frac{1}{n^4}+\frac{3}{n^8}}$$
it will be a $O(n^6)$.